# How to remove zeroes to the right

Tags: xml, regex, unix

I have a xml which has several numbers, something like this:

```
<xml>
<case1>
    <amount>3.140000</amount>
    <amount2>3.0000</amount2>
    <detail>
        <name>something</name>
        <earning>3.1000</earning>
    </detail>
</case1>
<case2>
    <amount>3.10000</amount>
</case2>
```

The xml is in a single line, and I'm testing with a regex like this:

```
echo "433.000" | sed -e 's/\([0-9]*\.\)\([1-9]*\)\(0*\)/\1\2/g'
```

But it gives me something like 3. for 3.00. I'm not trying to parse anything, just remove the zeroes. And somehow, it doesn't do anything when I try with:

```
sed -e 's/\([0-9]*\.\)\([1-9]*\)\(0*\)/\1\2/g' xmlFile.xml
```

I have to mention that I'm not good with regular expressions, and I'm on a hosted server, so I can't install any library or program, so only shell is allowed.

Thanks.

Comment: What's the benefit of removing the zeros?

Comment: And do you mean the "other left" than the conventional one?

Comment: What do you want the result to be for `3.000` - should it be `3.0` or `3` (which might cause an implicit type change from float to integer - not sure if you want that to happen)?

Comment: @RowlandShaw: It's the left from the computer's point of view, of course.

Comment: We need to compare the content of the file against a plain file that doesn't have the zeroes. The xml is produced by Informatica Powercenter, and we can't use XSLT.

Comment: The 3.000 should be changed to 3, because even though the type is different, the value is the same.

Comment: Which tool are you using to compare the two files?

Comment: @TimPietzcker That's brilliant, and by god I hope no one ever invents a programming language that makes you write from the computer's visual perspective. The problems with > and < alone would destroy us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work:

```
sed -e 's/\(\.[1-9][1-9]*\)0*/\1/g' -e 's/\.00*//' xmlFile.xml
```

This will result in the following:

```
<xml>
<case1>
    <amount>3.14</amount>
    <amount2>3</amount2>
    <detail>
        <name>something</name>
        <earning>3.1</earning>
    </detail>
</case1>
<case2>
    <amount>3.1</amount>
</case2>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried the first option but it tells me that r is an illegal option. Question, when I tried with

echo "3.1000" | sed -e 's/\(\.[1-9]\+\)0*/\1/g' -e 's/\.0\+//'

But it gives me the same string. Do you know why?

Comment: @StrayChild01 I removed the `-r` option since it won't work for you, try the current regex.  It is giving you the same string now because the parentheses are not escaped so the first expression is failing to match.

Comment: Hey, I tried the expression with the example, and it is showing me the same content. May be I'm doing something wrong? It is a Solaris 5.9

Comment: @StrayChild01 - Sorry, I am not very familiar with the differences in Solaris sed.  Try changing it to the following in case the `\+` is not working: `sed -e 's/\(\.[1-9][1-9]*\)0*/\1/g' -e 's/\.00*//'`

Comment: Great!  I edited my answer so that it now has the solution that worked.